# How can I redefine subsections and put them to the left?

Tags: sectioning

[image]

How can I change information in the redefined subsections?
I would like my \subsection to be on the very left of the document, but it is kind of indented.

I want my subsection just like the main part of the text pushed to the left. I inserted a photo. On the very top the subsection, followed by the text of which the first paragraph is indented.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\sffamily \Large \filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
```

Comment: This is not very clear. Could give more details  or post a sktch of what you're trying to obtain?

Comment: I inserted a photo hope it becomes more clear?

Comment: If I understand well, the first paragraph after the (sub)section title should not be indented?

Comment: the subsection itself look indented. I would like it to go to the very left like a non-indented text.

Comment: Please post a small compilable code that shows the problem.

Comment: all good it somehow solved itself.

Answer (score 1):

You are (mis-)using `\titleformat` to remove the section and subsection numbers, but you set the value for the space between number and title to `1em`. With option `hang` this space is used before the title even if the argument for the label is empty. So you have to change your settings to

`\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}`.

But then it would be better to change the counter `secnumdepth` to `0` and to use `\titleformat*` to change the font for subsections:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\sffamily \Large \filcenter}{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I know from your previous questions that you use **`scrreprt`**. *Do not use package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class!* So here is a suggestions using **KOMA-Script commands**:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,chapterprefix,sfdefaults=false]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\chapternumdepth}% only parts and chapters should be numbered
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\mdseries}% only some headings should be bold


\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\bfseries\large]{chapter}% does the same as \setkomafont{chapter}{\bfseries\large}
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}% center chapter headings

\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\sffamily\Large]{section}% does the same as \setkomafont{section}{\sffamily\Large}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\bfseries]{subsection}% does the same as \setkomafont{subsection}{\bfseries}

% format headings with style=section, eg. section, subsection and subsubsection
\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\centering #3#4}% centers section headings
    {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}% original definition for other section levels
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]